# Wix toolset - why isn't this second custom action running on installation?

Tags: wix

I have these two custom actions that need to be run during installation of my application. One is a windows form that takes user input, the other is supposed to execute an application that has just been installed. After all that the system needs to restart. However, the action that executes an application doesn't work. Here is what I have in `<InstallExecuteSequence>`:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action='UserInputCustomAction' After='InstallFinalize'>NOT Installed</Custom>
      <Custom Action='InstallRuntime' After='InstallFinalize'>NOT Installed</Custom>
      <ScheduleReboot After='InstallFinalize' />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

`InstallRuntime` is the action that runs the application. I've tried setting `After` to `UserInputCustomAction` but that also doesn't work. The application that needs to be run is installed to the target directory.

Here is how I've defined the custom actions:

```
<Fragment>
    <Binary Id="CustomActionBinary" SourceFile="$(var.GetUserInputAction.TargetDir)$(var.GetUserInputAction.TargetName).CA.dll"/>
    <CustomAction Id="UserInputCustomAction" BinaryKey="CustomActionBinary" DllEntry="GetUserInput" Execute="immediate" Return="check"/>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <CustomAction Id='InstallRuntime' FileKey='runthisplease.exe' ExeCommand='' Return='asyncNoWait' />
</Fragment>
```

I've tried putting `InstallRuntime` inside the same fragment as `UserInputCustomAction`, I've also tried adding the `Execute='Immediate'` tag to `InstallRuntime`, but it is still not running.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution.

I needed to add a reference to `WixUtilExtension.dll`.

Then I had to had to define my custom action like this:

```
<Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#RuntimeID]" />
<CustomAction Id='InstallRuntime' BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes" />
```

Where `[#RuntimeID]` refers to the file ID of what I am trying to run.

I could then call the second custom action after the first one like this:

```
<Custom Action='UserInputCustomAction' After='InstallFinalize'>NOT Installed</Custom>
<Custom Action='InstallRuntime' After='UserInputCustomAction'>NOT Installed</Custom>
```

Comment: [Did you base yourself on this sample from the WiX help file](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/run_program_after_install.html)?